# Return Value for Recursive Functions in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding a couple of things regarding recursive functions in Python (well, I guess in general). I tried looking for the answer but wasn't sure how to look for it either.

Taking the recursive function example most common when I search:

```
def sfactorr(j):
    if j == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return j * sfactorr(j-1)
```

each time the function is greater than 1, it starts again until j == 1. But when it hits 1, shouldn't the return value be 1? Obviously when you run it you get the result of the whole function, but I don't seem to fully understand why that is.

In other words, how come it returns the correct value and not the one the base condition is returning?

Thanks

Comment: Try evaluating `sfactorr(2)` by hand, step by step.

Comment: The return value is `1` when you hit `j==1`, but be aware than in the `else` you're multiplying that by `j`. There's a video tutorial about it that I was watching just yesterday (for Java, but the general idea still stands) https://youtu.be/ozmE8G6YKww

Comment: `each time the function is greater than 1, it starts again until j == 1.` is wrong what is really happening is `each time the function is different from 1, it starts again until j == 1.`

Comment: agree with @jwodder. try evaluating by hand. For example in case of sfactorr(2), when it hits 1 the if condition returns 1 to the else condition and you get 2*1=2. Try it.

Comment: Thanks, I was evaluating it but couldnt quite wrap my head around what was going on with the returns. I think the key was what Felippe Da Motta corrected in my reasoning about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work through the steps.

Say we pass 3 to the function.

When the function first runs, j > 1. So instead of returning 1, it returns j * [the function called with one less than j). But it can't actually return that until the function it called has returned.

It keeps on doing that until j is 1. That's the base condition. When j is 1, 1 gets returned to the function above it.

So. Starting with j == 3:

```
(1) j == 3, returning j * the result of (2)
(2) j ==2, returning j * the result of (3)
(3) j == 1, returning 1
```

So the functions are called in order (1), (2), (3), but return in order (3), (2), (1).

```
(3) returns 1
(2) takes the 1 from (3) and multiplies it by (2), resulting in 2. Then it returns that.
(1) takes the 2 from (2) and multiplies it by 3, resulting in 6. It returns that as a final value.
```

Recursive statements mean that the functions all collapse back into themselves, not that only the last statement runs.

Comment: I see, thanks for clearing that up. I'll go ahead and practice a bit until I get the hang of it.